# How to divide UIView N number of equal UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-graphics

I'm new to iOS, I want to divide the `UIView` frame in to `N` equals size UIView frame based on the center point of the `UIView`.

For Example i done for the circle:
http://s14.postimg.org/6w4xfa80h/i_OS_Simulator_Screen_shot_Mar_31_2014_7_03_03_P.png

Same way i have to do. but the shape of the view corner is not the arc, it should be same as view rectangle frame.

How can i achieve.

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: You have stated a goal. You have not asked a question. Even your goal is ambiguous. You say you want to divide a rectangle into a N squares. Then you say you want to divide a `UIView` into a group of equal-sized views. **Then** you mention pie slices, which is a completely different problem. **Then** you mention the center point of the view, without explaining what that has to do with the problem. Finally, you post a link to an article about dividing a piece of paper into an equal number of sections by folding it. In short, your post is a complete muddle.

Comment: I think for this is used UICollectionView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you're trying to do is creating views that look like the following:

[image: 8-way split]

Note that the areas are not rectangular, so they cannot be view frames. They are shapes that can be created via CGPath functions.
An easy way to create those lines is with `CGPathAddLineToPoint`. Always add a line that starts at the center of the view and goes down far the y coordinate. All you have to do is change the `CGAffineTransform *m` parameter by calling repeatedly `CGAffineTransformRotate` with an `angle = 2*pi/n` where n is the number of equal parts.

Assuming you have a `CGAffineTransform t` and the aforementioned angle, you'd loop n times:

`CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, CGAffineTransformRotate(t,angle), view.frame.center.x, view.frame.center.y + view.frame.size.y);
// Now do something with that line....`

Comment: #Rikkles ur correct, but in center i have one circle, which i mentioned in  about in pic. in  that case what will be the code for my CGPathRef....

Comment: Use `CGContextClip` with a graphics context containing the inside circle. It will then automatically clip the paths containing the lines.

Comment: #Rikkles actually each piece of view as individual view i need as the same shape. for that how can i write my CGPath points. like that above image each pie piece is individual view, i over written layoutSubview method for that shape.